# Devise auth without email and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it safe to use Devise gem for authentication and leave `email` and `password` fields empty? 
Some users in App are using "omniauth-facebook" login, which requires other parameters to login..

Comment: As far as I know Devise will still require the `email` from the user in order to create the token. Have a look at how [RailCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) does it here.

The user signs in with Omniauth and is asked to provide an `email` address so the Omniauth token can be assigned to a user.

Comment: In this RailsCast [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record) Ryan shows how to do guest authentication and does show a bit of devise. At about 5:50 in the screencast.

Comment: You can remove the validateble module or override the email required validation in Devise.